# How to set url to web which I get from web service

Tags: ios, for-loop, uiwebview

I get n number urls from the web service. On selecting didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I need to display url for that particular file. Please note that every row will have different url.
I stored the url in SaveDisplay class and SaveDisplay.m class has following code

## import "SaveDisplay.h"

```
@implementation SaveDisplay
@synthesize buttonName;
@synthesize urlForLoad;

- (id) initWithButtonName:(NSString *)_buttonName withUrlForLoad:(NSString *)_urlForLoad
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self -> buttonName = _buttonName;
        self -> urlForLoad = _urlForLoad;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Here's what Iam trying, but i need a proper way to loop it and set a url for respective file

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      
        SaveDisplay *objectForUrl = [[SaveDisplay alloc] init];
            WebViewController *webController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:Nil];
             webController.urlToLoad = objectForUrl.urlForLoad;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:webController animated:YES];
}
```

[image]

Comment: First of all, the way you operate variables is not safe and doesn't match general practice. Either use a `copy` modifier at the `NSString*` properties declaration and use their setters or use `self -> stringVar = [stringParam copy]`. Secondly, you are creating a new instance of `SaveDisplay` that have no value at `urlForLoad`. Instead find the instance of `SaveDisplay` that you should have stored somewhere after parsed the initial service response.

Comment: Can you also show the cellForRowAtIndexPath callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I solved the issue by adding this line

```
SaveDisplay *objectForUrl = (SaveDisplay *)[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Where tempArray is global `NSMutableArray`which contains the url.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about the function of your SaveDisplay class.
A more common way to achieve this would be:

1. Retrieve results from a webservice
2. Store them into a dictionary or array (or anything else than can be used as a datasource...).
3. Populate the tableview (from datasource in 2.)
4. When an item is selected
5. Get the URL for the selected item (from datasource in 2.)
6. Setup the view controller with the retrieved URL
7. Push the view controller

So you might want to make a convenience method like this:

```
- (NSURL *)getURLForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Find and return URL for given index path
    NSURL *documentURL = ...

    return documentURL;
}
```

Comment: The function of `SaveDisplay` type is to organize the data structure,  arrays and dictionaries of "standard" types is the most error-prone kind of data storage.